# Spring configuration: long value out of a String property

Tags: spring

I am configuring a scheduler task in spring in this way:

```
<bean id="someSchedulerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
        <!-- start after 60 seconds -->
        <property name="delay" value="6000"/>
        <!-- depends on the enviroment -->
        <property name="period" value="${period}"/>
        <property name="runnable" ref="myScheduler"/>
    </bean>
```

The property `period` is set up in some configuration file, and it seems that the default type is String:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someSchedulerTask' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Initialization of b
ean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long' for property 'period'; nested exception is ja
va.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "period"
```

How could I change in this step from Stirng to Long??

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
There is no problem with the place holder configuration, I am using more values from this config file in another beans.
Declaration:

```
period=30000
```

Comment: Have you tried `type="long"` ?

Comment: Show us your property placehold config and your context delimitations.

Comment: you can change the type to String ar java Class? and then cast to Long, Long.valueO....an control the NumbeFormatException..

Comment: Sorry you need to control if have well defined your file.properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1: Change your method to accept a java.lang.Long

2: Create a java.lang.Long yourself in spring:

```
<bean id="period" class="java.lang.Long">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${period}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="someSchedulerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
        <!-- start after 60 seconds -->
        <property name="delay" value="6000"/>
        <!-- depends on the enviroment -->
        <property name="period" ref="period"/>
        <property name="runnable" ref="myScheduler"/>
</bean>
```

or without the extra bean

```
<bean id="someSchedulerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
        <!-- start after 60 seconds -->
        <property name="delay" value="6000"/>
        <!-- depends on the enviroment -->
        <property name="period">
            <bean class="java.lang.Long">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="${period}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="runnable" ref="myScheduler"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

`${period}` is being read as a `String` instead of value of `${period}` i.e `period` is being assigned with value `${period}`.

For such properties to work, you need Property Placeholder. Add this to configuration

```
<context:property-placeholder location='period.properties'/> 
// Edit location
```

Then you can have

```
<property name="period" value='${period}'/>
```

Comment: The placeholder is correctly set up. I am using more values (string all of them) declared on it in other beans. 
The problem is that the period in the scheduler must be a long, and the values declared in a config file seem to be by default String

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is you have misspelled the fully qualified name of the class which loads the properties file.Hence spring is trying the convert the place holder string i.e "${period}" to int hence the error....

I used to get the same error while using the code

There were typos in two places..

Comment: No, that was not the problem. I fixed it with the given solution by @tom